# Extending Activity with FrameLayout over multiple activities with code reuse

Tags: android, android-activity, code-reuse, android-framelayout

I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. I have a `ChatActivity` using `FrameLayout` in frame.xml. This activity needs  to be reused across 5 activities. Is there anyway to do a code reuse? This acitivty runs independently of other activities.

For example, in activity A, which uses main.xml, I want `ChatActivity` and frame.xml to be included. What is the best way to achieve this besides merging the `ChatActivity` and frame.xml into activity A and main.xml? Merging the activities would mean that I have to copy and paste codes 5 times into different activities. I am not sure if this is the right way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "include" an `Activity` to another `Activity`. Since your `Activity` has a basic functionality that all your other `Activities` use, you could have all your `Activities` extend this basic `Activity`.

The best way though for you would be to use `Fragments` and the compatibility library.

Regarding layouts, you can have reusable ones and import them to your current layout using `include`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Use Fragments. you can create one Fragment and use the same in all activities. Fragments have their own view. Look at the following link for fragment.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

you can use fragments before 3.0 by including compatibility library.

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html

Answer (score 1):

I android you can reuse xml files by using the include tag like

```
<include layout="@layout/okcancelbar_button" android:id="@+id/okcancelbar_ok"/>
```

To share functionalites of an activity with other activities, create a base activity with common functionalites and make the other activities extend from it.